# facebook image uploading using as3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-as3-api

I am getting this error while we are uploading image to facebook.And i am given the permissions.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos

{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

This is my as3

```
var params:Object = {image:img, message:'vcxv', fileName:'vcxvc',name: 'My Card'};
Facebook.api('/me/photos', onSaveToPhotoAlbumComplete, params, "POST");
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an Access Token to Object:

```
access_token:Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken

var params:Object = {image:img, message:'vcxv', fileName:'vcxvc',name: 'My Card', access_token:Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken};
Facebook.api('/me/photos', onSaveToPhotoAlbumComplete, params, "POST");
```